# Is there a way I can make a button as default on a form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code:

```
<FORM ACTION="../cgi-bin/cgi4.pl">
Go to check-out page? 
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="checkout" VALUE="Yes"> 
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="checkout" VALUE="No"> 
</FORM>
```

I would like the Yes to be default when I click enter. Is this possible?

Comment: Click enter where? On some textbox? When you click enter the focus must be on some control e.g textbox

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use tab index property.

```
<FORM>
    <input type ="text" tabindex="3"/>
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="checkout" VALUE="Yes" tabindex="1" /> 
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="checkout" VALUE="No" tabindex="2" /> 
</FORM>
```

I would not use javascript as if a person does not want to submit and he presses 'enter' he would be forced to do that. Maybe he uses the search bar on the top of your webpage and presses enter, but both forms will be submitted.

http://jsfiddle.net/EUUcG/3/

---

But if that is not the case, you can use the javascript function:-

```
function searchKeyPress(e) {
    // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
    if (window.event) {
        e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.forms["myform"].submit();
    }
}
```

---

This one is better:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function() {
      document.getElementsByName("checkout")[0].focus();
    } 
</script>
```

by @mplungjan

Comment: Checked property on input boxes? [msdn? Nope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [MDC? nope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties)

Comment: I believe there is no such method called `click()` in vanilla JavaScript. You might want to use [`document.createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) (PS I did not downvote).

Comment: well i believe that, that `click()` existed but i don't know much. So here is my edited code

Comment: Yes there is a click event on buttons. There is no checked attribute except on checkboxes and radiobuttons. Hence the downvote

Comment: Yea i am aware of that, but earlier a person had answered that he had tested it on Opera and it had worked for him. So I added a both these properties. He probably deleted it since I had commented on his post about this. Well, i have edited and will be appreciating you undo of the votedown

Comment: `document.forms["myform"].submit();` won't POST `checkout=Yes` or `checkout=No`. One of the submit buttons must be clicked for the form to submit a value for checkout!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementsByName("checkout")[0].focus();
}
</script>
<FORM ACTION="../cgi-bin/cgi4.pl">
Go to check-out page? 
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="checkout" VALUE="Yes"> 
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="checkout" VALUE="No"> 
</FORM>
```

In HTML5 add autofocus to the button

`<input type="submt" name="checkout" value="Yes" autofocus>`

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mM9VJ/

Comment: What textbox? I see no steenkin' textbox here

Comment: yeah, he does not has, are you sure, will there be a page containing Yes on NO button? if yes, then I'm zipping my mouth :D

Comment: should'nt it be <input type="submit"...> quoted?

Comment: @mplungjan. What if the user shifts focus to the other button by pressing tab and then press enter key?

Comment: That is ok. OP wanted the YES to be DEFAULT. If the user decides to change the focus, then that is what is expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FORM ACTION="../cgi-bin/cgi4.pl">
    Go to check-out page? 
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT id='btnYes' NAME="checkout" VALUE="Yes" onclick="doSomething(); /> 
    <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="checkout" VALUE="No" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnYes').click()" />         
</FORM>
```

Please note: You need to add onkeydown on each control that you need to capture enter key on.

Comment: @mplungjan. Basically you need to have an onkeydown event on all the controls on which you need to capture the "Enter" key. The textfield provided in my solution previously was just an example. Check my updated answer.